# Postgresql Group_by error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, group-by

I am trying to do the following:

```
@business.placements.includes(:employee).group(:month).  order('points DESC').map(&:employee)
```

But I keep getting the following error (whenever I use group_by I run into problems because of my lack of postgresql knowledge):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "placements.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "placements".* FROM "placements" INNER JOIN "employee...
               ^
: SELECT "placements".* FROM "placements" INNER JOIN "employees" ON "placements"."employee_id" = "employees"."id" WHERE "employees"."business_id" = 43 GROUP BY month ORDER BY points DESC)
```

My schema looks as follows (if any help):

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :placements, through: :employees

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_many :placements

class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
```

Comment: if you select * you would need all columns in the group by

Comment: So would I have @business.placements.includes(:employee).group(:month, :other_column, :another_column).  order('points DESC').map(&:employee)

Comment: You're not using any aggregate functions, such as min(), max(), sum(), etc. You don't need the GROUP BY clause at all.

Comment: I'm going to use .first to get the first record from each month

Comment: `GROUP BY month` returns exactly one row for each value in the "month" column when you write a valid SQL query.

Comment: Did you search for the error message? You would've found a lot of information about just this.